# TikZ "scale" key not behaving at all in the expected way when scaling tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am having difficulty with TikZ remembering node positions, or just reconciling things between different coordinate systems (such as nodes named within a given coordinate system and then refered from outside of the coordinate system), when scaling the `tikzpicture`.

Here's a simple `standalone` document that I want including in my document.

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
    font=\scriptsize,
    x=.75cm,
    y=.75cm,    
    axis x line=center,
    axis y line=center,
    x axis line style={<->},
    y axis line style={<->},
    xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
    ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    xlabel style={below},
    ylabel style={left},
    xmin=-5.5, xmax=5.5,
    ymin=-5.5, ymax=5.5,
    }
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{myfncG}{1}{\pgfmathparse{ #1 + sqrt(#1^2+1)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fncLN}{1}{\pgfmathparse{ln(#1)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]%,scale=0.75]
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[domain=-5.5:2.5, blue, samples=200,line cap=round,arrows=<->]  {myfncG(x)} node [pos=0.25,above] (g) {};
  \addplot[domain=0.025:5.5, blue, samples=200,line cap=round,arrows=<->] {fncLN(x)} node [pos=0.95,above] (ln) {};
\end{axis}
  \node at ($(g)+(0,2ex)$) {$y=x + \sqrt{x^{2}+1\,}$};
  \node[anchor=east] at ($(ln)+(0,0.5ex)$) {$y=\ln(x)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which generates:

[image]

But in the master document, I want to rescale the image.  Here's an example of how I could approach this in the master document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

This time I'm using \verb=\includegraphics=

\includegraphics[width=2in]{combined}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

> [image]

But I'm not happy with the font size.  So, I thought I could just *rescale* the `standalone`.
That requires just one change in the first MWE.

Change

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]%,scale=0.75]
```

to

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,scale=0.75]
```

Then things go all wonky on me:

[image]

And notice that it's not just that the nodes for my annotations that get placed improperly, but also the labels for the axes' names.

I do have a work around.  I could use the following for my `standalone` document:

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
    font=\scriptsize,
    x=.75cm*0.75,%% <---- scaling HERE!
    y=.75cm*0.75,%% <---- scaling HERE!
    axis x line=center,
    axis y line=center,
    x axis line style={<->},
    y axis line style={<->},
    xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
    ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    xlabel style={below},
    ylabel style={left},
    xmin=-5.5, xmax=5.5,
    ymin=-5.5, ymax=5.5,
    }
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{myfncG}{1}{\pgfmathparse{ #1 + sqrt(#1^2+1)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fncLN}{1}{\pgfmathparse{ln(#1)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]%%,scale=0.75]
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[domain=-5.5:2.5, blue, samples=200,line cap=round,arrows=<->]  {myfncG(x)} node [pos=0.25,above] (g)  {};
  \addplot[domain=0.025:5.5, blue, samples=200,line cap=round,arrows=<->] {fncLN(x)}  node [pos=0.95,above] (ln) {};
\end{axis}
  \node at ($(g)+(0,2ex)$) {$y=x + \sqrt{x^{2}+1\,}$};
  \node[anchor=east] at ($(ln)+(0,0.5ex)$) {$y=\ln(x)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

[image]

But it seems that this is more of a hack than a general principal I should follow.  In fact, it can be a rather annoying work around when every time I want to generate coordinates and nodes with given coordinates, I've got to remember to include my scale factor:

```
\def\aesf{0.75}
\coordinate (A) at (3*\aesf,4*\aesf);
```

Additionally, I thought `scale` does not effect the font size.  According to the TikZ manual, `scale` should be multiplying the coordinate by the named `factor`.

But in this final MWE by changing the scale, you get different scaled labels too!  (I've chosen a ridiculously small scale to emphasize the effect.)

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
    font=\scriptsize,
    x=.75cm,
    y=.75cm,
    axis x line=center,
    axis y line=center,
    x axis line style={<->},
    y axis line style={<->},
    xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
    ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    xlabel style={below},
    ylabel style={left},
    xmin=-5.5, xmax=5.5,
    ymin=-5.5, ymax=5.5,
    }
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{myfncG}{1}{\pgfmathparse{ #1 + sqrt(#1^2+1)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fncLN}{1}{\pgfmathparse{ln(#1)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,scale=0.5]
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[domain=-5.5:2.5, blue, samples=200,line cap=round,arrows=<->]  {myfncG(x)} node [pos=0.25,above] (g) {\normalsize$y=x + \sqrt{x^{2}+1\,}$};
  \addplot[domain=0.025:5.5, blue, samples=200,line cap=round,arrows=<->] {fncLN(x)} node [pos=0.95,above left] (ln) {\normalsize$y=\ln(x)$};
\end{axis}
%  \node at ($(g)+(0,2ex)$) {$y=x + \sqrt{x^{2}+1\,}$};
%  \node[anchor=east] at ($(ln)+(0,0.5ex)$) {$y=\ln(x)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a better approach to this?  What am I not understanding about how `scale` works?

Answer (score 1):

Scaling only the `axis` environment works for me:

```
\begin{axis}[scale=0.75]
```

[image]

If you also want to scale the distance of the label nodes with the functions you can scale the rest of the image inside a scope. May be this is not necessary because that distances depend on the fontsize.

```
\begin{scope}[scale=0.75]
  \node at ($(g)+(0,2ex)$) {$y=x + \sqrt{x^{2}+1\,}$};
  \node[anchor=east] at ($(ln)+(0,0.5ex)$) {$y=\ln(x)$};
\end{scope}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
    font=\scriptsize,
    x=.75cm,
    y=.75cm,    
    axis x line=center,
    axis y line=center,
    x axis line style={<->},
    y axis line style={<->},
    xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
    ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    xlabel style={below},
    ylabel style={left},
    xmin=-5.5, xmax=5.5,
    ymin=-5.5, ymax=5.5,
    }
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{myfncG}{1}{\pgfmathparse{ #1 + sqrt(#1^2+1)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fncLN}{1}{\pgfmathparse{ln(#1)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\begin{axis}[scale=0.75]% scaling the axis environment
  \addplot[domain=-5.5:2.5, blue, samples=200,line cap=round,arrows=<->]  {myfncG(x)} node [pos=0.25,above] (g) {};
  \addplot[domain=0.025:5.5, blue, samples=200,line cap=round,arrows=<->] {fncLN(x)} node [pos=0.95,above] (ln) {};
\end{axis}
\begin{scope}[scale=0.75]
  \node at ($(g)+(0,2ex)$) {$y=x + \sqrt{x^{2}+1\,}$};
  \node[anchor=east] at ($(ln)+(0,0.5ex)$) {$y=\ln(x)$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In fact you already scale the plot using `x=0.75cm` and `y=0.75cm` and it is of course possible to change this values to 0.5625cm.

The key `/pgfplots/scale` only rescales the unit vectors `x` and `y` after the axis scaling based on `width` (that is an another possibility of scaling), `height`, `plot box Ratio`, `axis equal` or explicit unit vectors with `x`, `y` was computed. But it does not change text labels. Note there is a difference between `/pgfplots/scale` and `/tikz/scale`.

For further details have a look at section 4.10 Scaling options in the pgfplots manual.